# Android Gradle: what does "lintOptions abortOnError false" mean?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I wonder what mean the following lines :

```
buildTypes {
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
```

May you help ?

Is it recommended or not recommended to use these lines?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[Lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html) is a tool which helps to find potential bugs in the code, as well as checking code style, etc.

It can be either enabled or disabled for the project. If it is enabled, it will abort the app build when certain bigger issues are discovered. The "abortOnError" flag allows to ignore this error and continue with building the app.

Ideally, you would fix the error rather than suppress it. Suppressing using this flag could be useful for debug builds if you know that the error is there, but don't want to deal with it straight away, or maybe another team member is dealing with it, etc. However, it is marked as an error for a reason, so in general it's not really recommended to ignore them, especially for production builds.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html)

```
android {
  ...
  lintOptions {
    // if set to true (default), stops the build if errors are found.
    abortOnError false   
  }
}
...
```

> Is it recommended or not recommended to use these lines?

There isn't a general rule but in my opinion you should avoid using this configuration in a release build.

Comment: What does it matter? This is just for code linting right, it doesn't matter if it's release mode?

Answer (score 0):

```
  lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
  }
```

This means it will run lint checks but won't abort the build if any lint error found. By default, its true and stops the build if errors are found.

Suppose a scenario like QA is blocked with build and the developer couldn't able to fix within the time, then we can give the `abortOnError false` and give build to QA. Then we should fix the issue before moving to production.

Little bit documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html)

Answer (score 0):

Lint tool by android is for improving your code the reliability and efficiency of your Android apps. For example, if your XML resource files contain unused namespaces, this takes up space and incurs unnecessary processing. Other structural issues, such as use of deprecated elements or API calls that are not supported by the target API versions, might lead to code failing to run correctly.
Now using this in gradle as

```
lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
```

will run lint checks but won't abort the build. Follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html#overview) if you want to know about lint.